# A problem in A Course in Point Set Topology by Conway, union of totally bounded sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

This is stated as a problem in *A Course in Point Set Topology* book by J. Conway:

> Let $\{E_n\}$ be a sequence of totally bounded sets. If $\operatorname{diam}E_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, show that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ is also totally bounded.

How  can  we  prove  this  statement? I  have  no  idea  to  use  diameter  conception  to  this  problem  (it  has  relation  with  Cauchy  sequence).

Comment: This  is  problem  from  J.Conway  A  Point  Set  Topology  book

Comment: As stated, it's obviously false, just let $E_n=\{n\}\subseteq\mathbb Z$. And why is this tagged as general topology when it's obviously about metric spaces?

Comment: Are  you  sure?  what  about  diam(E_n)

Comment: It's false without some other assumption. For another example, consider $E_n = (n - \dfrac1n, n + \dfrac1n) \subset \Bbb R$. I looked up the book you are using, and found the relevant problem (1.4 exercise 5), and **it is indeed stated exactly as above**, so I don't know what's going on here (a misprint, perhaps).

Comment: So, downvoters please note: **this question is unanswerable as it is (because the statement is false), but not due to any error on the part of OP; the book in question does indeed have this exact wording**.

Comment: Thanks  it is  good  counterexample.  Ok  i  understood  that  there  is  problem  in  the  condition  of  this  question

Answer (score 2):

As stated, it's obviously false, just let $E_n=\{n\}\subseteq\mathbb Z$.   -- [user2345215](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1093249/a-problem-in-a-course-in-point-set-topology-by-conway-union-of-totally-bounded#comment2228818_1093249)

It's false without some other assumption. For another example, consider $E_n = \left(n - \dfrac1n, n + \dfrac1n\right) \subset \Bbb R$. I looked up the book you are using, and found the relevant problem (1.4 exercise 5), and **it is indeed stated exactly as above**, so I don't know what's going on here (a misprint, perhaps). -- [BaronVT](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1093249/a-problem-in-a-course-in-point-set-topology-by-conway-union-of-totally-bounded#comment2228881_1093249)